# Is this statement equivalent to $f(x)\in\mathscr C(a,b)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I'm pondering on the following:
$$f(x)\in\mathscr C(a,b)\overset{?}{\Longleftrightarrow} f(x)\in\mathscr C[a+\delta,b-\delta]\quad\forall\delta\in(0,\frac12(b-a)) $$
I believe it's true. The $\implies$ part is trivial. For the $\Longleftarrow$ part, clearly $\forall x_0\in(a,b)$, $\exists \delta\in(0,\frac12(b-a))$ s.t. $x_0\in(a+\delta,b-\delta)$. Since $f(x)\in\mathscr C[a+\delta,b-\delta]$, it immediately follows that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, and hence $f(x)\in\mathscr C(a,b)$.
This seems to be rathe simple. But for me I haven't yet seen it explicitly mentioned in any textbooks I have read. Perhaps it's because I've read too few books.
Anyway, I want verification for this perspective. Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen that the restriction of a continuous function is continuous?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know what a "restriction" of a function is. Would you care to elaborate a bit? @bburGsamohT

Comment: Actually that may not be specifically what you want, I'll write up an answer to explain what I am thinking.

Comment: @bburGsamohT Many thanks.

Comment: It's true, your proof is fine, but yes, it is rather simple.

Comment: @zhw. Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show $f(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ by showing that, for all $p$ in $(a,b)$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ so that $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$ if $|p-q|<\delta$.

Let $p\in (a,b)$. As $(a,b)$ is an open interval, there exists some $c$ so that $p\in [a+c,b-c]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. We know by assumption that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a+c,b-c]$, so there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$ if $|p-q|<\delta$. This is really all there is to it. As $f(x)$ is continuous at all points of $(a,b)$, we can conclude that it is continuous on $(a,b)$.